# GET Acumatica attached Public File without Authentication

Tags: acumatica

When I have a File in Acumatica (such as an Inventory Item image) it has an "External Link" property such as https://.../Frames/GetFile.ashx?fileID=bdb9534c-6aa9-41fa-a65d-3119e32b0fe5

Even if the file is marked with "Is Public (the file ignores access rights and is visible to everybody)" this only works in the context of a signed in user. Logging out and attempting to access the file results in a redirect to the Acumatica Login.  I need to be able to access these "Public" files externally without being logged into Acumatica such as in an <img src".." /> tag of a different site. Is there any way to achieve this? Is this the intended function of "Is Public" as it reads like the file should still be accessible with no authentication necessary.  (Acumatica 2018 R1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IsPublic files are visible to all logged in user and files are not served as static http resources. So even if you were able to see the image in the browser with the GetFile link I don't think it would work as the URL for SRC attribute of IMG tag which requires a static image resource.